# Paraview script to export position in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, paraview

I have `vtk` files from a numerical simulation that I usually visualize with `ParaView`. And I would like to plot some results in a `LaTeX` document. To do so, I like to use `CSV` files. The good thing is that `Paraview` can export data into `CSV` files. Therefore, I am able to export the complete time sequence of the variable density into a sequence of `CSV` files.

BUT, I would like to have the position included in theses `CSV` files.

Here is what I can do now:

```
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
import os 
#### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()


### MY VARIABLES
Folder_output='E:\\My Documents\\VTKfiles'
FileNames_list=[os.path.join(Folder_output, f) for f in os.listdir(Folder_output) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(Folder_output, f))]
nb_tStep=len(FileNames_list)
Arrays_out_list=[ 'Structured Coordinates:0', 'Structured Coordinates:1' ,' Structured Coordinates:2', 'density',]
CSV_File_Names='E:/My Documents/Results'


for t in range(0,nb_tStep):
    output_LBM_ = LegacyVTKReader(FileNames=FileNames_list[t] )

    ####
    PassArrays1 = PassArrays() 
    PassArrays1.PointDataArrays =  Arrays_out_list
    source = PassArrays1 
    writer = CreateWriter(CSV_File_Names+"{}.csv".format(t), source)
    writer.FieldAssociation = "Points" # or "Cells" 
    writer.UpdatePipeline() 
    del writer
```

Comment: Did you get something with your current code? I think it is incomplete as your data are stored inside output_LBM_ and It does not seem to be passed as a source to your CSV writer.

Comment: Yes I get a CSV file with the "density" variable. The operation `PassArrays()` get the information from the reader, if I understand well. So it is passed correctly as a source to the CSV writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) three options to retrieve your points and variables from a VTK legacy file using the Paraview or/and VTK APIs.

## Using the Paraview API

```
from paraview.simple import *
cylindervtk = LegacyVTKReader(FileNames=['./cylinder.vtk'])
SaveData('./output.csv', proxy=cylindervtk)
```

and run it using `pvpython`:

```
pvpython vtk_output_csv.py
```

You will get a CSV file similar to this one:

```
"density","Points:0","Points:1","Points:2"
1.2,0.5,0.5,0
1.2,0.5,-0.5,0
1.2,0.40451,0.5,-0.29389
1.2,0.40451,-0.5,-0.29389
1.2,0.15451,0.5,-0.47553
1.2,0.15451,-0.5,-0.47553
1.2,-0.15451,0.5,-0.47553
1.2,-0.15451,-0.5,-0.47553
1.2,-0.40451,0.5,-0.29389
1.2,-0.40451,-0.5,-0.29389
1.2,-0.5,0.5,-6.1232e-17
...
```

which you could use later on a script (Python or whatever else) to perform some post-processing or plotting actions.

## Using the Paraview and VTK APIs

Although the first option is very concise, you have to write your data on your hard-drive, and you may have to reload them later. If you want to perform you post-processing or plotting actions in only one python script, then you are writing temporary data on the hard-drive for nothing.

The following code leverages the [numpy integration with VTK](https://blog.kitware.com/improved-vtk-numpy-integration/). It enables you to load your coordinate and point data into numpy arrays, and to export them at the end in a CSV file (or to whatever else):

```
from paraview.simple import *
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
import numpy as np

#Paraview reader
pv_reader = LegacyVTKReader(FileNames=['./cylinder.vtk'])

#Fetch the reader data and store them locally into a VTK object
vtk_data = servermanager.Fetch(pv_reader)

#Wrap the vtk_data VTK object to get the coordinates and PointData as numpy arrays
vtk_dataset_adapter = dsa.WrapDataObject(vtk_data)

coords = vtk_dataset_adapter.GetPoints()
density = vtk_dataset_adapter.PointData['density']

data_export = np.column_stack((coords,density))

header = "X Y Z density"
np.savetxt("output2.csv", data_export, header = header)
```

## Using solely the VTK API

The last one is very similar to the second one, yet it only uses the VTK API:

```
import vtk
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa
import numpy as np

#PolyDataReader must be modified depending on the type of the Legacy VTK input type
reader = vtk.vtkPolyDataReader()
reader.SetFileName("cylinder.vtk")
reader.ReadAllFieldsOn()
reader.Update()
vtk_data = reader.GetOutput()

vtk_dataset_adapter = dsa.WrapDataObject(vtk_data)

coords = vtk_dataset_adapter.GetPoints()
density = vtk_dataset_adapter.PointData['density']

data_export = np.column_stack((coords,density))

header = "X Y Z density"
np.savetxt("output3.csv", data_export, header = header)
```

This solution can be interesting as it only has VTK as dependency, but also work with the `pvpython` shipped with Paraview as VTK is a dependency of Paraview.

Comment: Thank you for these three options. With the option 1, I get a CSV file with the columns "density" plus some other variables that I don't want and without the coordinates of the points ! Otherwise, using your options 2 and 3, when I call `coords = vtk_dataset_adapter.GetPoints()`, I get the error message:
`AttributeError: 'vtkCommonDataModelPython.vtkImageData' object has no attribute 'GetPoints'`. Maybe this is linked to the fact that my vtk files are using an structured dataset. Is there a way to change these unwanted effects (extra variables and no coordinates) for all your solutions ?

Comment: The options 2 and 3 works fine for me with a small modification:
`coords = np.zeros((vtk_dataset_adapter.GetNumberOfPoints(),3))
  for i in range(vtk_dataset_adapter.GetNumberOfPoints()):
   coords[i,0], coords[i,1], coords[i,2] = vtk_dataset_adapter.GetPoint(i)`